# How to show detailed order history on woocommerce product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a donation site that I am working on that is using woocommerce. The "products" are actually different nonprofits. I am trying to show a detailed donation history on each of the product's pages. So basically show a list of orders, that will display the customer's name, date, as well as the price. I have this working except that if a customer donates to multiple nonprofits (buys multiple products on one order) then it shows the total amount for the order, not just that line item that matches the current product. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code that I'm using on the "content-single-product.php" page:

```
echo '<h2>Previous Donations for this Nonprofit</h2>'; 
$products = array();
foreach (get_posts('post_type=shop_order&numberposts=-1&post_status=publish') as $order) {
    $order = new WC_Order($order->ID);
    foreach($order->get_items('line_item') as $item) {
        $product_id = (!empty($item['variation_id'])) ? $item['variation_id'] : $item['product_id'];
        $products[] = $product_id;
    }

    if (in_array($post->ID,$products)) {        
        echo '<br>Date: '.$order->order_date; 
        echo '<br>Name: '.$order->billing_first_name . '&nbsp;'  .$order->billing_last_name;
        echo '<br>Email: '.$order->billing_email; 
        echo '<br>Order Total: $'.$order->get_line_total( $item );      
    }   
}
```

This is the var_dump of the $order variable

    `Object(WC_Order)#622 (14) {
      ["order_type"]=>
  string(6) "simple"
  ["id"]=>
  int(246)
  ["post"]=>
  object(WP_Post)#660 (24) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(246)
    ["post_author"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["post_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-09-02 13:36:24"
    ["post_date_gmt"]=>
    string(19) "2016-09-02 17:36:24"
    ["post_content"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_title"]=>
    string(42) "Order – September 2, 2016 @ 01:36 PM"
    ["post_excerpt"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_status"]=>
    string(12) "wc-completed"
    ["comment_status"]=>
    string(6) "closed"
    ["ping_status"]=>
    string(6) "closed"
    ["post_password"]=>
    string(19) "order_57c9b89850215"
    ["post_name"]=>
    string(25) "order-sep-02-2016-0536-pm"
    ["to_ping"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["pinged"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_modified"]=>
    string(19) "2016-09-03 12:08:48"
    ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
    string(19) "2016-09-03 16:08:48"
    ["post_content_filtered"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_parent"]=>
    int(0)
    ["guid"]=>
    string(70) "http://sitename.com/?post_type=shop_order&p=246"
    ["menu_order"]=>
    int(0)
    ["post_type"]=>
    string(10) "shop_order"
    ["post_mime_type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["comment_count"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
  }
  ["order_date"]=>
  string(19) "2016-09-02 13:36:24"
  ["modified_date"]=>
  string(19) "2016-09-03 12:08:48"
  ["customer_message"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["customer_note"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_status"]=>
  string(12) "wc-completed"
  ["prices_include_tax"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["tax_display_cart"]=>
  string(4) "excl"
  ["display_totals_ex_tax"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["display_cart_ex_tax"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["formatted_billing_address":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["formatted_shipping_address":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
}`

Comment: A little more info would be helpful. What have you tried so far? Could we see a var_dump of $order?

Comment: I can output the total for the order like I said. My problem is that I need the line item price in the order that matches the 'product' that is currently being viewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're showing the info for the order and not the item. You want to print the content based on the item instead, like this:

```
echo '<h2>Previous Donations for this Nonprofit</h2>';
foreach (get_posts('post_type=shop_order&numberposts=-1&post_status=wc-completed') as $order) {
    $order = new WC_Order($order->ID);

    foreach($order->get_items('line_item') as $item) {
        if ($post->ID == $item['product_id'] || $post->ID == $item['variation_id']) {
            echo '<br>Date: '.$order->order_date; 
            echo '<br>Name: '.$order->billing_first_name . '&nbsp;'  .$order->billing_last_name;
            echo '<br>Email: '.$order->billing_email; 
            echo '<br>Order Total: $'.$order->get_line_total( $item );   
        }  
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what version of WooCommerce you're running, but I got an error when trying to query posts with a post_status of publish. Version 2.2+ wants you to check based on their proprietary post statusi. You see that reflected above.